# Best way to create a temporary directory on AWS Lambda Function with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, temp

Possibly being a bit knit-picky, but does anyone know of a more "elegant" method for doing this?

Right now I create tmp directories like this:

```
tmp_file_path_obj = Path(mktemp(dir=f"/tmp/path/to/nested/dir/with/non/existent/parents"))
tmp_file_path_obj.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
```

I would like a method that takes advantage of something like `mkdtemp` but when I try that I get FileNotFound errors since the parent directories don't exist yet and I'm not able to pass in the `exist_ok` or `parents` parameter.

I guess I'm looking for some equivalent to `mkdtemp(dir="path/to/dir", exist_ok=True, parents=True)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import tempfile

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()